# Возможно ли такое при помощи flexbox?

Tags: css, css3

Пытаюсь решить задачу, используя flexbox. Возможно ли поместить красный див `.fluid` под желтый `.right` не используя доп дивы (так как при определенном разрешении `.fluid` будет вновь занимать 100% ширины)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div {
  padding: 15px;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
}
.left img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.right {
  flex: 1 50%;
  background-color: gold;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.fluid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x450">
  </div>
  <div class="right">Donec iaculis rutrum lectus molestie commodo. Fusce ultrices eros justo, id bibendum augue malesuada eu. Nulla et lectus consequat justo rutrum mollis. Ut eget ligula orci. Sed vel nibh sit amet nulla rhoncus tincidunt. Donec commodo at sem at sodales.
    Praesent cursus ante in dolor venenatis pulvinar.</div>
  <div class="fluid">Nullam ultricies est non odio posuere dictum. Cras auctor lacus aliquet, varius felis in, commodo est. Suspendisse sed velit eu metus aliquet placerat. Sed scelerisque lectus eu enim malesuada, nec luctus lectus consectetur. Phasellus lectus nisl, cursus
    gravida metus sit amet, auctor posuere neque. Vestibulum ornare neque augue, quis sollicitudin tellus tristique in. Morbi nec luctus nisi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а какая разметка этих трех дивов?

Comment: У `.left` возможна фиксированная ширина? Или возможна ширина в процентах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя flexbox решения видимо нет, но используя float: left для блока .left, а для 2-х других overflow: hidden получается именно то, чего требовалось добиться.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что это возможно с помощью flexbox.
Однако необходимого поведения можно добиться с помощью CSS с некоторыми оговорками:

- Нужно указывать конкретную ширину для блока `.left` (в пикселях или процентах)
- Нужно пользоваться [`calc()`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc) для точного расчета размеров блоков `.right` и `.fluid`, если ширина блока `.left` указывается в пикселях
- Вместо `flex` нужно использовать `float`

Вот пример реализации

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 40px; /* Для демонстрации */      
  overflow: auto;
}
.container div {
  padding: 15px;
}
.left {
  background-color: green;
}
.left img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.right,
.fluid {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
.right {
  background-color: gold;
}
.fluid {
  background-color: red;
}
@media(min-width: 480px) {
  .left {
    float: left;
    width: 330px;
  }
  .right {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 330px);
  }
}
@media(min-width: 762px) {
  .fluid {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 330px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://satyr.io/300x450">
  </div>
  <div class="right">Donec iaculis rutrum lectus molestie commodo. Fusce ultrices eros justo, id bibendum augue malesuada eu. Nulla et lectus consequat justo rutrum mollis. Ut eget ligula orci. Sed vel nibh sit amet nulla rhoncus tincidunt. Donec commodo at sem at sodales.
    Praesent cursus ante in dolor venenatis pulvinar.</div>
  <div class="fluid">Nullam ultricies est non odio posuere dictum. Cras auctor lacus aliquet, varius felis in, commodo est. Suspendisse sed velit eu metus aliquet placerat. Sed scelerisque lectus eu enim malesuada, nec luctus lectus consectetur. Phasellus lectus nisl, cursus
    gravida metus sit amet, auctor posuere neque. Vestibulum ornare neque augue, quis sollicitudin tellus tristique in. Morbi nec luctus nisi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Решение опробовать можно на [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venzell/ne7v8sh7/) или здесь же, нажимая на кнопку "Выполнить код", а затем последовательно на кнопку "На всю страницу" и "Закрыть".

Я позволил себе добавить две точки перехода для случая, когда и первый блок не вмещается на экран. Кроме того, картинка теперь отзывчивая и при малых размерах экрана пропорционально уменьшается.

Comment: Суть в том, что блоки должны быть резиновыми. На самом деле все оказалось гораздо проще, используя `float: left` для блока `.left`, а для 2-х других `overflow: hidden`)

Comment: Я потому и задавал уточняющий вопрос под вашим сообщением, чтобы на основе вашего ответа дать какую-либо рекомендацию. Если нужны резиновые блоки, замените в моем примере `330px` на `30%` для `.left` и `calc(100% - 330px)` на `70%` для блоков `.right` и `.fluid`. Если вы нашли совершенно другое решение - добавьте его в качестве ответа.

Comment: Если нужна полная зависимость ширины от контента без указаний каких-либо значений или пропорций, то в вашем случае необходимо использовать либо табличную верстку, либо javascript.